# R Warning: In lformula NaNs produced

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am working with R. I am trying to follow the instructions here and make a "level plot" : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lattice/versions/0.10-10/topics/levelplot

I generated some data for this example:

```
library(lattice)
a <- rnorm(100,10,10)
b <- rnorm(100,5,5)
c <- rnorm(100,1,1)
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Then, I tried to make the "level plot":

```
levelplot(c~a*b, d, cuts = 50,  xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
          colorkey = TRUE, region = TRUE)
```

This seemed to run, but produced a warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In levelplot.formula(c ~ a * b, d, cuts = 50, scales = list(log = "e"),  :
  NaNs produced
2: In levelplot.formula(c ~ a * b, d, cuts = 50, scales = list(log = "e"),  :
  NaNs produced
```

And the resulting plot (left) looks very "empty" compared to the usual outputs for this function (right):

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to take the log of negative numbers.  Remove `scales=list(log="e")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck : Thank you for your reply! I had tried that earlier - but unfortunately, this did not make any difference.

Comment: Not true.  There are no warnings if you follow my comment.

Comment: The warnings disappear, but the plot is still empty

Comment: It is not empty.

Comment: more or less empty

Comment: or is this maybe just on my side?

Comment: More or less empty is not empty.

Comment: maybe the problem is the data I am using for this question